# Class not found: Sending Mail Using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is first time i'm getting this error for the class which i already have imported in my controller..
I know this question has been asked before but i want to solve this error.

I get below error when i hit submit button.

> Class 'App\mail\LayoutMail' not found
>
> Mail::send(new LayoutMail());

**My File:**

[image]

**Uses:**

```
use Mail;
use App\mail\LayoutMail;
```

**My Controller:**

```
    $token = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');
    if($token)
    {
         DB::insert('INSERT INTO mail (subject,message,firstname,lastname,contact,email,store_number,transaction_number,transaction_date,status,created_at) VALUES 

         (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[


           $subject,$message,$fname,$lname,$contact,$email,$storenum,$transactionnumber,$datetransaction,'Unread',$now


        ]);

        Mail::send(new LayoutMail());

        \Session::flash('message', 'Successfully submitted!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    else
    {
        \Session::flash('message', 'Failed to submit!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`..?

Comment: hi.. chuk. in my localhost. may work is fine. however in my server which i already upload on production. i got that error.

Comment: Oh. Try running `composer dump-autoload`, let's see how it goes.

Comment: chuk. i already use composer now.. but still same error

Comment: they error pointed this. Mail::send(new LayoutMail());

Comment: Is there a file called `app/mail/LayoutMail.php` in your install? Or is it at `app/Mail/LayoutMail.php`?

Comment: yes.. there is a file..

Comment: hi ceejoyz.. I update my content i upload where i have the file..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer why my function is not working because of the Capitalization must be use ..

use App\mail\LayoutMail;

to

use App\Mail\LayoutMail;